# Where can I find Visual Studio style tabs in either a built-in or 3rd party component?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, controls

I want to get Visual Studio style tabs (you know, the ones where you can tab through the currently opened files).

Is there a 3rd party component that does this?

How hard would it be to do myself?

Answer (score 2):

Try http://devexpress.com/free - they have a bunch of cool looking, high quality WinForm controls. The one you will probably be most interested in is [XtraTabControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/editors/XtraTabControl.xml).

They are FREE, which is the best part =)

Answer (score 1):

Divelements [SandDock](http://divelements.co.uk/net/controls/sanddock/) is the best choice for me. The controls are very targeted, simple to work with and well documented.